# How can I list all modified files from 2020 on a server?

Tags: linux, find

I need to list all the modified files starting from / recursively.
Only the 2020 files. I have tried several commands with find but it does not work.

Comment: What commands have you tried? You might be almost there

Answer (score 1):

With the GNU implementation of `find`, the one generally found on non-embedded OSes that use Linux as their kernel (though that syntax is not GNU specific as it was actually first introduced as a user-contributed patch for BSD), you can do:

```
find / -type f -newermt 2020-01-01 ! -newermt 2021-01-01
```

Note that it will include files last modified at exactly 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 and not those last modified at 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000000. In practice, it's virtually impossible that files be created at those exact nanoseconds, but that can still happen in practice for files that have been extracted from archives that didn't store times with nanosecond precisions, or files whose timestamp have been tampered with with `touch -d 2020-01-01` for example.

Another approach with GNU `find` is to do:

```
find / -type f -printf '%TY%p\0' | LC_ALL=C sed -zn 's/^2020//p' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

That is, get `find` to print the file's year of last modification followed by path in NUL delimited records and then use `sed` to filter records that start with 2020.

With `find` implementations that don't support `-newermt`, you can create reference files with `touch` and compare with the standard `-newer` predicate:

```
mkfifo first last
touch -d 2020-01-01 first
touch -d 2021-01-01 last
find / -type f -newer first ! newer last
```

(here creating them as fifo files instead of regular files, so they are not selected by the `-type f`).